# How to validate data entered in the sign up form created in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-authentication

I have created a registration form using the class models.User ([refer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#using-the-django-authentication-system)) in Django as follows:

```
from Django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        confirm_password = request.POST['confirm_password']

        if password == confirm_password:
            # some code
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)
            user.save()
            return redirect('login')

        else:
            return redirect('register')

    return render(request, 'register.html')
```

**My problems:**

1. Now I want to make **Full Name as optional** but **all other fields as required**, also I want to apply length constraint on my fields, how can I do that? As this is an inbuilt model ([class models.User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#using-the-django-authentication-system)), I am not sure how to set **blank=True** or use **max_length** for any field.
2. Also I want to remove the spaces (if any) at the end and beginning of the entered data, before saving it using `user.save()` (e.g. if someone entered the name as **"  abc efg   "** I want to save it as **"abc efg"**). Basically, I want to use `.is_valid()` feature of the Django forms. I even tried doing that as:

   ```
   from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
   from django.contrib.auth.models import User

   def register(request):
       if request.method == 'POST':

           form = User(request.POST or None)

           if form.is_valid():
               username = request.POST['username']
               email = request.POST['email']
               password = request.POST['password']
               confirm_password = request.POST['confirm_password']

               if password == confirm_password:
                   # some code
                   user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)
                   user.save()
                   return redirect('login')

               else:
                   return redirect('register')

           else:
               return redirect('register')
       return render(request, 'register.html')
   ```

but this is giving me the following error: `'User' object has no attribute 'is_valid'`

**Any ideas about how can I make the fields optional/required and set the max_length of the fields & remove the trailing spaces (if any)** all while using the inbuilt model [class models.User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#using-the-django-authentication-system)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a form first. If you are using default django user, then you can user [`UserCreationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) to validate the data:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           # rest of the code
```

Now, lets say you want want to clean the data which you get from the HTML form, then you can use `clean_<field_name>` method. To do that inside `UserCreationForm`, you can override it(also adding some code to show how to customize forms):

```
class CustomUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.') 
    def clean_first_name(self):
       return self.cleaned_data['first_name'].strip()
```

Please see the documentation for more information on [validation and cleaning data in forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).

Comment: okay, so what I understood from your solution is that the django `User` which I used in my code above is a `model` and to validate the data before saving in the model I need to create a `Modelform` separately & instead of creating my own form I can use `UserCreationForm` (which can even be overridden to add some fields or conditions), did I get you right?

Comment: One more doubt in UserCreationForm there are 3 pre-defined fields username, password1 and password2....so when I do form.save() will the `password1` (==password2) from the `UserCreationForm` be automatically saved in the `password` of `User` model? I am confused because password  has different names in the UserCreationForm and User model

Comment: Yep, you got it right. And password field should be fine as you are using Django’s user model

Comment: Ohh nice, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

As per the django docs, it is best to create your own user model by inheriting from the AbstractBaseUser: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model
There you can define what's optional and what not.

Oh, and while you're at it - maybe it's also worth looking at [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html). Maybe not too relevant right now but for sure down the road! Also check out the custom forms.